# Kotlin Poet ambigouos imports

Tags: kotlin, annotation-processing, kotlinpoet

Let's say I have two interfaces in a project:

```kotlin
interface InterfaceA {
    // ...
    interface Listener {
        // ...
    }
}

interface InterfaceB {
    // ...
    interface Listener {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and I declare both of them and their listeners for annotation processing using Kotlin Poet's `ClassName`, eg.

```kotlin
fun InterfaceA() = ClassName(
    packageName = "com.example.a",
    simpleNames = arrayOf("InterfaceA"),
)

fun InterfaceAListener() = ClassName(
    packageName = "com.example.a.InterfaceA",
    simpleNames = arrayOf("Listener"),
)

fun InterfaceB() = ClassName(
    packageName = "com.example.b",
    simpleNames = arrayOf("InterfaceB"),
)

fun InterfaceBListener() = ClassName(
    packageName = "com.example.b.InterfaceB",
    simpleNames = arrayOf("Listener"),
)
```

The class I have to generate uses all of the aforementioned types: `InterfaceA`, `InterfaceA.Listener`, `InterfaceB`, `InterfaceB.Listener`. That results in generating the following imports, producing compilation error due to ambigouos `Listener` imports.

```kotlin
import com.example.a.InterfaceA
import com.example.a.InterfaceA.Listener
import com.example.b.InterfaceB
import com.example.b.InterfaceB.Listener
```

Is there any way to get rid of the listener imports, since they're not really necessary? Or is there any other way to approach the issue?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's not at all what happens. KotlinPoet handles this correctly by using aliased imports for the listeners. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Actually, the way you create `ClassName`s is also incorrect. `Listener` is not in a package called `com.example.a.InterfaceA`. You should do something like `InterfaceB().nestedClass("Listener")`. Either way, KotlinPoet can resolve the conflict.

Comment: Hi, @Sweeper! The nested class is exactly what I needed. Creating `ClassName`s in such a way was a silly mistake on my part. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Listener`s aren't actually in a package called `com.example.a.InterfaceA` or `com.example.a.InterfaceB`. They are *nested* types in `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB`.

You can create `ClassName`s representing nested types using the `nestedClass` method.

Example:

```
val listenerA = ClassName("com.example", "InterfaceA").nestedClass("Listener")
val listenerB = ClassName("com.example", "InterfaceB").nestedClass("Listener")
FileSpec.builder("", "Foo")
    .addProperty(
        PropertySpec.builder("foo", listenerA).build()
    )
    .addProperty(
        PropertySpec.builder("bar", listenerB).build()
    )
    .build()
    .writeTo(System.out)
```

This outputs:

```
import com.example.InterfaceA
import com.example.InterfaceB

public val foo: InterfaceA.Listener

public val bar: InterfaceB.Listener
```

Notice that only `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB` are imported.

---

Even if the `Listener`s are not nested types, and are actually top-level interfaces in different packages. KotlinPoet can still resolve the conflict by using aliased imports.

That is, if you actually did:

```
val listenerA = ClassName("com.example.InterfaceA", "Listener")
val listenerB = ClassName("com.example.InterfaceB", "Listener")
```

KotlinPoet would generate:

```
import com.example.InterfaceA.Listener as InterfaceAListener
import com.example.InterfaceB.Listener as InterfaceBListener
```